# How do I populate a cell based on multiple criteria in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

So here is the situation. I have one spreadsheet in Google sheets that has a column for the names of TV stations. I have a second column that lists airing times for ads. This is the format the date and times are in.

14-12-22 08:06:05

I have a second sheet that has the same column for TV station names. I also have a column that has a time range in the format

09:00-16:00

Then there is a third column for Rate.

What I am trying to do is add a Rate column to the first spreadsheet and populate that my matching up the TV Station name and the time range on the second sheet. My first thought was a VLOOKUP but I'm trying to match 2 conditions with the second one being a bit tricky since I am using an exact time vs a time range.

Any ideas?

Comment: I could do that with the second sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As it is permitted to parse the time intervals I would recommend doing so (say with something like `=SPLIT(A1,"-")` since the results might then be arranged into a compact matrix such as shown in the image in ColumnsF:J. The differences in the rates for different stations at different times are readily apparent.

I have left the above in the same sheet as one with a representation of your other data since I (am lazy and) don't know the relevant sheet names anyway - but prefix the relevant sheet name (and `!`)  to the column references in the formula that are later in the alphabet than `C`:

```
=vlookup(A2,F:J,match(C2,$G$1:$J$1,1)+1,0)
```

With extraction of the time element (into ColumnC) of your data (from ColumnA) the formula attempts to find the time from C in the first row, but accepts an inexact comparison by defaulting to the next lower value where there is no exact match. Once found, the MATCH() function returns the position of the match relative to the start of the range searched.

This is then used in a VLOOKUP() function to determine how far across to return the result of a search for the exact A column value in ColumnF.

Details of the syntax of the functions may be found via Help > Function list.

[image: SO27722122 example]

Comment: Hmmm. What if the data is on a second tab. Here is the URL for a sampling of what I am doing.  - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TyMIz79ni2Z2FTal7Jwa1zmgB5BLitCvZYgZ-XLRm6I/pubhtml

Comment: What I want to do with the data at that URL above is look for a match of the network, day and time on the second sheet and return the rate from column H and place it in the Rate Test column on the first tab –

Comment: Can anyone can help with this?